# ASP.NET Web API with DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: rest, oauth, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am building RESTful web API for my ASP.NET MVC4 web application using ASP.NET WebAPI. I want to use OAuth 1.0 to provide authorization. I'm looking toward of DotNetOpenAuth library. Can anyone help me to understand how to use the service provider of this library with ASP.NET WebAPI?

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a similar situation as you.
I would recommend you to take a look at [Thinktecture's IdentityModel Authorization extensions for Web API](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http) (and MVC).
It's a open source project hosted on GitHub, with samples to take a look at as well.

You can also grab a lot of useful info from [Dominick Baier's blog](http://www.leastprivilege.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the OAuthServiceProvider sample that comes with DotNetOpenAuth?  It demonstrates a WCF service that is protected by OAuth 1.0.

Comment: Thank you for respond. Yes, I looked at this sample (and [ASP.NET MVC 2 OpenID web site template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef)). But it is difficult to understand the sample (and the library) without any documentation and example of using with any explanation. I still can not adapt it to ASP.NET WebAPI, but I am trying. But I'm not sure that I could do it, and that I will not spend the time to waste.